# How to measure voltage at a node between source and ground?

Tags: voltage, ground

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuCqa3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I understand that VA = 1.5 V and VB = -1.5 V, but I am not able to understand the voltages at C and D.

Is the voltage at C 0 V or -1.5 V?
Is the voltage at D 0 V or 1.5 V?

Can someone explain this?

Comment: (Anywhere "in the ground net", voltage *to ground* is zero. Other than in reference to a pre-agreed reference, there is no voltage at any single potential.)

Comment: On top of that @greybeard already said, anywhere in _any_ net is the same voltage throughout (referenced to any other net).

Comment: If you have 1.5V at VA, and V1 is a 1.5V supply, what else VC would be than 0V, because you have 1.5 from VA to VC, or VAC. Same applies everywhere else. And you have explicitly also put a ground reference which means 0V to node which is both points VC and VD.

Comment: When two points are connected together with a wire, do they have the same voltage?

Comment: thank you all for replying. I am just started learning about circuits. I understand that the symbol between C and D is ground and ground is 0v. My confusion started when,  in one of the lectures, my instructor wrote -1.5 at B. So based on that, why is C not -1.5v?

Comment: thank @Justme. I have one more follow up question. Assume there is no node C, A and V1 and circuit is only node B, V2, D and D is connected to ground. In this case, is voltage of D still 0? D is connected to + 1.5v and ground, so which one wins?

Comment: @JenParker You define what is 0V by placing the Ground symbol on it. The battery still has 1.5V over it's terminals, no matter which side you set as reference.

Answer (score 2):

The symbol between "C" and "D" is the "signal ground" symbol and defines the node where the voltage is 0. So no matter what other circuit elements are there (In a correctly drawn consistent circuit), the node connected to signal ground has a voltage of 0 V.

As a matter of fact, the voltages at "A" and "D" can only be uniquely determined after knowing one reference voltage, in this case the voltage at "C"/"D".

Furthermore, the "voltage source" symbol doesn't mean that there is a specific voltage (like 1.5 V in this case) at the positive terminal, it means that the positive terminal is 1.5 V above the negative terminal, it gives only a relative information, not an absolute

Comment: thank you Ken Grimes, for replying. I am just started learning about circuits. I understand that the symbol between C and D is ground and ground is 0v. My confusion was in one of the lectures, my instructor wrote -1.5 at B. So based on that, why is C not -1.5v?

Comment: -1.5 V at B is correct, because the voltage source on the right says that node B is 1.5V lower than node D, which by definition is 0V

Comment: C is 0 V because is connected to signal ground, which by definition has a voltage of 0 V

Comment: thank you Ken Grimes. I have one more follow up question.  Assume there is no node C, A and V1 and circuit is only node B, V2, D and D is connected to ground. In this case, is voltage of D still 0? D is connected to + 1.5v and ground, so which one wins?

Comment: Ken Grimes, why is not C -1.5v as one side of C is connected to -1.5v?